# Convert array to decimal

Tags: php, bitmap

I have this code:

```
public function get_names($number){
  $names = array(
    'None',
    'Anton',
    'bertha',
    'Cesa',
    'Dori',
    'Egon',
    'Frank',
    'Gollum',
    'Hans',
    'Kane',
    'Linus',
    'Moose',
    'Nandor',
    'Oliver',
    'Paul',
    'Reese');

  $bin = strrev(decbin($number));
  $len = strlen($bin);
  $output = array();
  foreach(str_split($bin) as $key=>$char)
  {
    if ($key == sizeof($names)){
      break;
    }
    if($char == 1)
    {
      array_push($output,$names[$key]);     
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

When I now call the function with number - let's say - 32256 I would get an array with "Kane, Linus, Moose, Nandor, Oliver, Paul".

Can anyone tell me what I would have to do when I want to give a certain names array and wanna get the number as a result where the certain bits are included? So exactly the other way around.

I found that code somewhere which works fine. But I need it vice versa.

Thanks in advance!

Andreas

EDIT: I want to know the decimal number when I e.g. have an array with "Anton, bertha,Cesa". I want to store those in a database instead of storing arrays with names each time. And when I need the names I just take the decimal number from database and use my function to get my name arrays.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, why would the input `32256` have the result `Kane, Linus, Moose, Nandor, Oliver, Paul`? Can you explain how each of those names are selected?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton this function already returns that result. But I don't undestand a problem too

Comment: It's a case of take 32256 - convert to binary - 0111111000000000 and then pick the items out of the array if there is a 1 in that position.

Comment: Well, as far as I understand the code (sine this is not mine as I told before) the function at first takes the number (32256) reverse it and converts it into binary. Then it iterates through all digits and checks if the digit is 1 for a certain name and add it to an array.

Comment: why don't you save array keys like 1,2,3 instead of storing array names then you can easily get array names when you fetch those keys.

Comment: @Sayed Mohd Ali this is ofc possible. But not the solution for my problem. Thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just take the position in your `$names` array as being the bit position, you raise 2 to this position to give it the correct bit position and keep a running total of the items found...

```
$input = ["Cesa", "Gollum", "Hans"];
$output = 0;
foreach ( $input as $digit )    {
    $output += pow(2,array_search($digit, $names ));
}
echo $output;   // 392
```

with

```
$input = ["Kane", "Linus", "Moose", "Nandor", "Oliver", "Paul"];
```

gives

```
32256
```

Or as Barmar points out in his comment, you can save the lookup by inverting the names array using `array_flip()` which will mean that looking up each key will give the position in the array...

```
$output = 0;
$names = array_flip($names);
foreach ( $input as $digit )    {
    $output += pow(2,$names[$digit]);
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: Better to use `array_flip($names)` instead of searching

Comment: @Barmar, thanks, I've added that option to the answer.

Comment: Works great! Thanks to both of you  !!